# Laravel Http client before request send add headers

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, guzzle, laravel-http-client

I'm using Http client for making outgoing HTTP requests. I've used it many places in the project.Now project has new requirement that I have to add a new header to every outgoing
requests. I can do this by adding it to every places. But I want to know , is there any kind of trigger or event which can give me ability to modify the headers just before the request send. There is an event Illuminate\Http\Client\Events\RequestSending which is only useful for inspecting the request.

Comment: If you use guzzle client instance you can add a handler stack and make a function middleware for guzzle lets say add_header() to it which can be called via handler you can call it via withOptions it is just a idea have not tried yet for httpclient

Comment: Thank you @bhucho , This is actually what I was looking for. My header fp-signature depends on the request body and params , by adding the handler I can get these things in handler and can create the fp-signature. This solution works. Thanks

Comment: I will try it tomorrow and post an answer here, it is a nice question will be helpful in future.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible to achieve without the need of a package. You can simple do something like this in a service provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Factory as Http;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->extend(Http::class, function ($service, $app) {
            return $service->withOptions(['foo' => 'bar']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with a fantastic package [here](https://github.com/smokills/laravel-http-client-default-options). After installing the package you just set the default headers like,

```php
Http::withDefaultOptions([
     'headers' => [
         'X-Bar-Header' => 'bar'
     ],
]);
```

But I was unfortunate, the package was not installed with my laravel 9-dev. So I had to extract the code for me. First, create a Factory class in your app\HttpClient directory,

```php
<?php

namespace App\HttpClient;

use Illuminate\Http\Client\Factory as BaseFactory;
use Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

class Factory extends BaseFactory
{
    protected $ignoreDefaultOptions = false;

    protected $defaultOptions = [];

    public function ignoreDefaultOptions()
    {
        $this->ignoreDefaultOptions = true;

        return $this;
    }

    public function withoutDefaultOptions($keys = null)
    {
        if ($keys === null) {
            return $this->ignoreDefaultOptions();
        }

        if (func_num_args() > 1) {
            $keys = func_get_args();
        }

        $this->defaultOptions = with($this->defaultOptions, function ($options) use ($keys) {
            foreach (Arr::wrap($keys) as $key) {
                Arr::forget($options, $key);
            }

            return $options;
        });

        return $this;
    }

    public function withDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        $this->defaultOptions = array_merge_recursive($this->defaultOptions, $options);

        return $this;
    }

    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        if (static::hasMacro($method)) {
            return $this->macroCall($method, $parameters);
        }

        if ($this->defaultOptions && ! $this->ignoreDefaultOptions) {
            return tap(new PendingRequest($this), function ($request) {
                $request->withOptions($this->defaultOptions)
                    ->stub($this->stubCallbacks);
            })->{$method}(...$parameters);
        }

        return parent::__call($method, $parameters);
    }
}
```

Then, create a HttpServiceProver,

```
php artisan make:provider HttpServiceProvider
```

And put the following code there,

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Factory as BaseFactory;
use App\HttpClient\Factory;

class HttpServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            BaseFactory::class,
            function ($app) {
                return new Factory($app->make(Dispatcher::class));
            }
        );
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Now, register the newly created service provider in AppServiceProvider.php

```php
public function register()
{
    //...
    app()->register(HttpServiceProvider::class);
}

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    //....
    Http::withDefaultOptions([
        'headers' => [
            'X-Bar-Header' => 'bar'
        ],
    ]);
}
```

There are other options in this package. Please check it [the package link](https://github.com/smokills/laravel-http-client-default-options) for details.